# NullReferenceException in MvvmCross Messenger

Tags: android, xamarin, viewmodel, mvvmcross

This is code in my ViewModel

```
public ICommand GoToCartCommand{
        get{ 
            return new MvxCommand (() => {                  
                var cartViewModel = Mvx.Resolve<CartViewModel>();
                if (cartViewModel != null)
                {
                    cartViewModel.cartlist.Add(new CartItemViewModel() { Name = Name, ID = ID, UnitPrice = double.Parse(Price), Quantity = 1, Description = Description, Image = Image });
                }
                cartListCount = cartViewModel.cartlist.Count;
                var messanger = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>();
                var message = new MyMessage(this,"Product has been added",cartListCount);
                messanger.Publish(message);
            });
        }
    }


public class MyMessage : MvxMessage
{
    public int CartList_Count{ get; set;}   
    public string Message{ get; set;}

    public MyMessage(object sender,string _message,int _cartlist_count) : base(sender) { 
        this.Message = _message;
        this.CartList_Count = _cartlist_count;
    }
}
```

This is code in my View :

```
  var messenger = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>();
_token = messenger.Subscribe<MyMessage>(OnInputIsNeeded,MvxReference.Strong);


private void OnInputIsNeeded(MyMessage _Message)
{
        Toast.MakeText (this.Activity,_Message.Message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```

My problem here is when I comeback to this view after going to next view `OnInputisNeeded` the method is called two times.
And when go back from this view and when I again come to this view and click button I get a `NullReferenceException`.

What is the solution?

What is the meaning of this: 
**Nothing registered for messages of type MvxSubscriberChangeMessage**

How do i register `MvxSubscriberChangeMessage`?

Comment: I've already answered this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694275/getting-messege-twice-using-imxmessenger/32697159#32697159

Comment: As for _MvxSubscriberChangeMessage_, this is an internal message that you can subscribe to just like anything else. Mvx outputs a diagnostic for any published message that doesn't have a subscriber. If you don't care about this message, you can simply ignore it.

Comment: Yeah,Thanks It works completely !!@@!! @killman