# Getting Messege Twice Using IMvxMessenger

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am working on Xamrin Android Application and I am using MvvmCross.In my application I have used IMvxMessenger.But I am getting messsge twice when I change the view and comeback to same view.And then It is Crashed.
What is the solution ?
Here is my code : 
In ViewModel I have this code :

```
var messanger = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>();
var message = new MyMessage(this,"Product has been added",cartListCount);
messanger.Publish(message);
```

And On View I have this code:

```
 private MvxSubscriptionToken _token;

 public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
         {
        var view = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

         messenger = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>();
        _token = messenger.SubscribeOnMainThread<MyMessage>(OnInputIsNeeded,MvxReference.Strong);

         return view;
         }

    private void OnInputIsNeeded(MyMessage _Message)
    {
        Toast.MakeText (this.Activity,_Message.Message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        messenger.Unsubscribe<MyMessage> (_token);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Views (whether Activities or Fragments) are created and destroyed all the time. Since you are subscribing in *OnCreateView()*, you should unsubscribe in *OnDestroyView()*.

What's likely happening is that *OnCreateView()* is being called multiple times and causing multiple subscriptions to be added. *MvxMessenger* is broadcasting the message to all subscribers. If a View is destroyed, but hasn't unsubscribed, it's likely to crash since the callback no longer exists.